# how can I collect the array heroes in my android studio project below

Tags: android, eclipse, android-json

my function is

```
public String[] loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    String[] heroes = new String[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       // heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
        heroes[i]= "https://static.pexels.com/photos/1543/landscape-nature-man-person-medium.jpg";
    }
    return heroes;
}
```

this is where i called it but it is returning null array for me

```
String s="";
try {
    items= loadIntoListView(s);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: share your json response

Comment: Your JSON is invalid

Answer (score 0):

The line `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);` may be crashing due to `json` not being a valid json array. This would cause the array to be null, as it hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: now please help me to initialize it or should i send you my full code. because i want a method that will retrieve and images name from my database(php/mysql) and return a string array holding those images name

Comment: @SagirYusufMuhammad You have to fix the mistake with your json string. If you need help with that please update your question to include the string you are trying to parse. It would probably be helpful if you were to also post the stack trace.

Comment: String s=null;  // string i am passing
            try {
                items= loadIntoListView(s);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Answer (score 0):

Your exception handler out of for. If you catch exceptions in for body, you can parse verified json items. If a item not correct, you can pass.

For example,

```
public String[] loadIntoListView(String json) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    ArrayList<String> heroes = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) 
    {
        try{

           JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           heroes.add(obj.getString("name"));

       }catch(JSONException ignore_errors){

       }
    }
    return heroes.toArray(new String[0]);;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, i did that but is showing me: expected string[], but found Arraylist.  please i want the heroes to be string array and the method loadIntoListView to be returning heroes array. thanks

Comment: thanks so much search it seemed like i am close to but it is still showing me error in json. i mean this line JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

Comment: your json must be wrong. Can you share it or validate on this link. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org @SagirYusufMuhammad